# Watir webdriver_unable to click Cancel Target button on popup window

Tags: webdriver, watir

I am VERY new to Watir, trying to test a popup window and am unable to get my script to click the Cancel Target button.  When running the script, I get an error: `element not visible (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError`.  This is the script I am using:

```
browser.div(:class => "modal-footer").button(:class => "btn btn-danger").click
```

Below is the code:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="target_modal" data-bind="with: target">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 data-bind="text: BusinessName"></h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span3">
                <label for="FirstName">First Name</label><input id="FirstName" type="text" data-bind="value:FirstName" />
                <label for="LastName">Last Name</label><input id="LastName" type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" />
                <label for="Email">Email</label><input id="Email" type="text" data-bind="value: Email" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="click: saveTarget">
            <i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i>
            Save Target
        </button>

        <button class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="icon-white icon-remove"></i>
            Cancel Target
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this popup is part of the page (ie just an div tag overlaying the rest of the page), rather than a new browser window popup.

My guess is that Watir is trying to click the button before the popup finishes being displayed. Explicitly telling Watir to wait for the button may solve the problem:

```
cancel_button = browser.div(:class => "modal-footer").button(:class => "btn btn-danger")
cancel_button.when_present.click
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly.  Tried the above and the script timed-out:  C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir-webdriver/wa
it.rb:30:in `until': timed out after 30 seconds, waiting for {:class=>"btn btn-d
anger", :tag_name=>"button"} to become present (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.4/lib/watir
-webdriver/wait.rb:98:in `method_missing'
        from targetcustomer.rb:29:in `<main>'

Comment: 2 possibilities come to mind. (1) The popup is not being displayed. The above code assumes that you already triggered the popup to be displayed. If you watch the script run, do you see the button you want to click? (2) There are multiple of these `<div class="modal-footer">` elements. Watir picks the first one in the html, not the first visible one. If you add a `puts browser.divs(:class => "modal-footer").collect(&:visible?)`, what do you get?

Comment: (1) I do see the button when the script runs.  (2) On the cmd window, 3 'false' are returned when I add the puts browser.divs(:class => "modal-footer").collect(&:visible?)

Comment: Okay, my guess is that the cancel button you want is not in the first modal-footer div element. We need to scope the locator to look in the right modal-footer. Is the `target_modal` id unique - ie what do you get with `browser.elements(:id => 'target_modal').length`?

Comment: I got it to work.  Your 1st answer got me thinking and this worked:  cancel = browser.div(:id => "target_modal")
cancel.div(:class => "modal-footer").button(:class => "btn btn-danger").i(:class => "icon-white icon-remove").click

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Justin Ko's 1st answer got me thinking and this worked:

```
cancel = browser.div(:id => "target_modal") 
cancel.div(:class => "modal-footer").button(:class => "btn btn-danger").i(:class => "icon-white icon-remove").click
```