# Watir webdriver - modal popup - Other element would receive the click

Tags: popup, webdriver, watir

I want to click an element on the modal popup window.
[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102433/watir-webdriver-unable-to-click-cancel-target-button-on-popup-window) helped me a lot with finding appropriate element, but it seems like other div is chosen (and actually clicked).
Popup code is:

```
<div id="reports-loader" class="modal" tabindex="-1" style="">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Super Title</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src="//some_source" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="">
    </iframe>
    <div id="reports-loader-skip-intro">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-large welcome-button skip gray" style="display: inline-block; width: 33%">Skip</a>
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-large welcome-button skip try-now-redirect" style="display: inline-block; width: 66%">Try Feature</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="reports-backdrop"></div>
```

The `"reports-backdrop"` div is to be the grey area covering the whole browser window, beneath the popup  (the `"reports-loader"`).

The code I am using to get the **Skip** link is:

```
popup = @browser.div(:id => 'reports-loader', :class => 'modal')
puts popup.div(:class => 'modal-body').a(:text => 'Skip').exists?
popup.div(:class => 'modal-body').a(:text => 'Skip').click
```

and `puts` returns the **true**.
Unfortunately, the wanted element is not clicked, but the `"reports-backrop"` div is used:

```
true # <-- the puts printout

    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (101, 115). Other element would receive the click: <div id="reports-backdrop" style="opacity: 0.7141267829936161;"></div>
      (Session info: chrome=35.0.1916.153)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
    (eval):1:in `process_watir_call'
```

What is OK in the whole situation - it seems like the button is actually clicked, since popup disappears (with no clicking it stays on the screen). Unfortunately, due to the error a test is failed.
Does anyone have some clues...?

Comment: It's possible that the element does exist but isn't enabled.  You could try [waiting](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver/wiki/AJAX-and-waiting-for-elements) for the element to become enabled.  For example: `popup.div(:class => 'modal-body').a(:text => 'Skip').when_present.click`

Comment: Thank you for the tip and editing! I tried the `when_present` and the result is exactly the same (the same error).
What is really strange to me: when I put a `sleep 10` BEFORE clicking - result is the same. But when I put `sleep 5` AFTER clicking, everything goes well (and click is done earlier that 10 sec after showing popup, so the `sleep 10` before should be enough). To me this is ....strange

Comment: I have followed also [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20882871/is-enabled-method-available-on-watir-and-or-page-objects-for-a-link) what resulted in (I am using the PageObject): `link(:skiper, :text => 'Skip')`/.../ `wait_until{ !skiper_element.attribute('disabled') }`
`puts 'Waited'`. I gets the printout Waited, but ...error is still the same. Till now the `sleep` after clicking workaround works fine, but I have no idea why.

Comment: If a wait _after_ the click solves the problem... could it be so that the problem is in the next step? I would assume that the next action is a click on the page, but that click occurs before the modal (and the grey area) disappears, so the element to be clicked is covered with that grey area which, logically, gets this click. Solution: wait for the modal/grey area to disappear after the click on skip link and before the next action.